# Time Series Data Mining Library?

Tags: time-series, classification, clustering

Can anyone recommend a library for time series data mining tasks other than predictive modeling and statistical analysis? There seem to be a number for these purposes (e.g., Gretl), but nothing for the tasks of:

- Classification
- Clustering
- Subsequence search
- Anomaly detection
- Motif discovery
- Indexing

I can't be the first person to want to use, e.g., [iSAX](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/iSAX/iSAX.html), but Googling hasn't turned up anything other than a single [Java library](https://code.google.com/p/jmotif/).

Links to anything that one could interface with C/C++, Python, or Julia are especially welcome, but any help would be appreciated. Assurance that such a library does not exist would be helpful as well, since I would then know it wouldn't be a waste of time to write one...

Answer (score 1):

The machine learning asks that you have listed can be covered by [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) in python - 
Classification, clustering , anomaly detection

Indexing can be done with [whoosh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/) (again python)

Additionally one can use **Pandas in Python** (which can do time series data analysis although more of statistical techniques) along with sklearn.
I doubt that a single library can do all of time series analysis.